# Limiting TextField inputs

Tags: java, netbeans, jtextfield

I'm trying to make a textfield that limits a user input.
I have this code:

```
 private void jTextField5KeyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                     
//This limits the input:
 if(jTextField5.getText().length()>=2) {
    jTextField5.setText(jTextField5.getText().substring(0, 1));
}
}
```

It successfully limits the input. However, when I tried to press other characters on the keyboard, it changes the last character on the textfield.
Any ideas to stop this? I know others will say that I should use Document(Can't remember) in making this kind of stuff, but I can't. I don't know how to do it in netbeans.
Please help.

Comment: You can extend [`PlainDocument`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/PlainDocument.html) for that.

Comment: use the `DocumentSizeFilter` class

Comment: Can someone show me how to do that? I'm really slow in this kind of things. I'm sorry :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a simple way to do it:

```
private void textFieldKeyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                       
 if(textField.getText().length()>=2) {  
   evt.consume();
 }
}
```

Comment: You already mark it :)
The checkbox on the left side is green now, which means you mark this as a correct answer..

Comment: There's a problem, when I changed 2 to 11, there's a conflict.

Comment: what conflict did you get?

Comment: -1 This is a bad approach which can lead to document mutation errors, does not take into account what will happen if the user pastes text or calls `setText` on the field.  A [`DocumentFilter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html#filter) would be a more sutiable solution

Comment: Works fine for me. NetBeans has an interface to attach such an event listeners to element. Open your swing object class file. Go to design mode. Then select an element that you want and hit the right mouse button. From the context menu that appears, choose properties. In the properties dialog, go to the Events tab ;).

Answer (score 0):

Try this Example which Use [PlainDocument](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/LimitJTextFieldinputtoamaximumlength.htm) :

```
class JTextFieldLimit extends PlainDocument {

private int limit;

JTextFieldLimit(int limit) {
    super();
    this.limit = limit;
}

JTextFieldLimit(int limit, boolean upper) {
    super();
    this.limit = limit;
}

public void insertString(int offset, String str, AttributeSet attr) throws BadLocationException {
    if (str == null) {
        return;
    }

    if ((getLength() + str.length()) <= limit) {
        super.insertString(offset, str, attr);
    }
}
}

public class Main extends JFrame {

JTextField textfield1;
JLabel label1;

public void init() {
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    label1 = new JLabel("max 10 chars");
    textfield1 = new JTextField(10);
    add(label1);
    add(textfield1);
    textfield1.setDocument(new JTextFieldLimit(110));///enter here the Maximum input length you want
    setSize(300, 300);
    setVisible(true);
}


}
```

Comment: Can you explain those codes to me? I'm not really good at this. I can't understand what super or other stuff does.

Comment: here this  a  tutorial for what `super` mean :http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html

Comment: and another one for `PlainDocument` http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/PlainDocument.html

Comment: Now how can I do that on netbeans?

Comment: -1 This is a bad approach which can lead to document mutation errors, does not take into account what will happen if the user pastes text or calls `setText` on the field.  A [`DocumentFilter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html#filter) would be a more sutiable solution